# Loop Div's Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to get a loop to work where as one fades in the other fades out.

My code so far

```
setInterval(function() {
    jQuery(".loop").each(function(index, k) {
        jQuery(this).delay(1200 * index).fadeIn(600, function(){
            jQuery(this).fadeOut(600);
        });
    });
}, 1200);
```

Example what happens : http://www.timoleon.co.uk/new/

It seems sometimes it works,  sometimes it will show two .loop divs? Any ideas?

Comment: In the first iteration `index` is zero, and `0 * 1200 == 0`

Comment: I understand this but what could i change to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're calling the function every `1200` milliseconds, once the first element is done fading out, the function is called again and it starts fading in again while the last function is still going, meaning the second element is fading in. Thus, both elements are fading in and both elements are showing.

Try changing it to `setTimeout(function() { [...] }, 2400)`. That way, the second element will fade in and out before the first element fades in again.

```
setInterval(function() {
    jQuery(".loop").each(function(index, k) {
        jQuery(this).delay(1200 * index).fadeIn(600, function(){
            jQuery(this).fadeOut(600);
        });
    });
}, 2400);
```